# read images as input to the Apache Beam pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, apache-beam

I would like to make Machine Learning Pipeline using Apache Beam that reads images from local folder, and then preprocess it. I found some examples of how to deal with .txt ot .csv file as an input to the pipeline. Like:

```
lines = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)
```

but, what about image data? let's say I would like to read an image, preprocess, make prediction, and then write desired output to local folder. How to do that?

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Beam does not have its own built-in support for processing images. But it does let you call any Python image-processing library from within a user-defined ParDo transform.